# Wi-Fi Network is not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, 16.04

I just updated to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04. I didn't check my WiFi connection earlier, but now I want to use WiFi. But, when I try to use my WiFi, it doesn't show up on the list and I can't use it.

I'm not sure what should be done.

```
ifconfig :
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a4:ba:db:c3:a7:da  
          inet addr:192.168.2.33  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a6ba:dbff:fec3:a7da/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:71031 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1925 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5047517 (5.0 MB)  TX bytes:266195 (266.1 KB)
          Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:289 (289.0 B)  TX bytes:289 (289.0 B)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:172.18.202.149  P-t-P:10.0.1.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
          RX packets:1561 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1722 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:829243 (829.2 KB)  TX bytes:204197 (204.1 KB)

###################################
iwconfig

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

ppp0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

###################################
lshw :
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 78:e4:00:2a:8f:7e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:17 memory:f69fc000-f69fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 13
       serial: a4:ba:db:c3:a7:da
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 duplex=full ip=192.168.2.33 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:28 memory:f68fc000-f68fffff ioport:de00(size=256)

###################################
lspci :
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
###################################
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 :
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
###################################
rfkill :
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
###################################
scan : 


ppp0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Failed to read scan data : Network is down

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
###################################
```

Please let me know if any more information is required.

Output are below as you mentioned :

sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source : 
Successfully exetued

sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer:
Once I execute this got this as below :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
firmware-b43-installer is already the newest version (1:019-2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dkms gstreamer0.10-gconf lame libaften0 libavcodec54 libavdevice53
  libavfilter3 libavformat54 libavresample1 libavutil52 libfaac0 libfdk-aac0
  libgdict-common liblavfile-2.1-0 liblavjpeg-2.1-0 liblavplay-2.1-0
  libopenjpeg2 libquicktime2 librhythmbox-core8 librtmp0 libswscale2 libvpx1
  libx264-142 mjpegtools mjpegtools-gtk rhythmbox-mozilla twolame
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

After that I have changed to BCM4312 device from software update and reboot the system. Device is using alternate driver.

Still it is not working.

[Sofware Update Device Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgktt.png)

Comment: `wl` is wrong for 4315. Sometimes it is blocked by `rfkill` if you install a wrong one.

Comment: It's BCM4312, and wl is the right driver from personal experience. I am also inclined to think it's a hardware switch.

Comment: I have attached this earlier as well. Any way

Answer (score 0):

You installed a wrong wireless driver. Connect to the internet and run these commands

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: Hi I did what you mentioned :

Comment: OK. Please post output of `rfkill list` TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: I have attached this earlier as well. Any way output of 
rfkill list:
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: You need to find the hardware switch or reset BIOS to defaults.

Comment: In BIOS setting it was already enabled. So I disabled it and again enabled it then I can see WIFI networks. After get connected with WIFI 
I am not able to use internet. "nmtui" cmd displayed that my connection is activated but I cant access internet. 
FYI, when i connect to same WIFI network with same credentials from windows laptop then it works fine. 
Please suggest.

Comment: Please suggest.